# Labels on Bar Chart are not working properly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~Course.lvl, ~GRDE_CODE,  ~n, ~rel.percent,
  "100-level",        "A", 95,      "22.1%",
  "100-level",       "A-", 30,         "7%",
  "100-level",        "B", 69,      "16.1%",
  "100-level",       "B-", 24,       "5.6%",
  "100-level",       "B+", 20,       "4.7%",
  "100-level",        "C", 70,      "16.3%",
  "100-level",       "C-", 16,       "3.7%",
  "100-level",       "C+", 25,       "5.8%",
  "100-level",        "D", 33,       "7.7%",
  "100-level",       "D+",  3,       "0.7%",
  "100-level",        "F", 44,      "10.3%",
  "200-level",        "A", 24,      "15.2%",
  "200-level",       "A-", 12,       "7.6%",
  "200-level",        "B", 22,      "13.9%",
  "200-level",       "B-", 10,       "6.3%",
  "200-level",       "B+", 17,      "10.8%",
  "200-level",        "C", 14,       "8.9%",
  "200-level",       "C-", 15,       "9.5%",
  "200-level",       "C+", 13,       "8.2%",
  "200-level",        "D", 13,       "8.2%",
  "200-level",       "D+",  3,       "1.9%",
  "200-level",        "F", 15,       "9.5%",
  "300-level",        "A", 32,      "36.8%",
  "300-level",       "A-", 11,      "12.6%",
  "300-level",        "B",  8,       "9.2%",
  "300-level",       "B-",  9,      "10.3%",
  "300-level",       "B+", 10,      "11.5%",
  "300-level",        "C",  6,       "6.9%",
  "300-level",       "C-",  1,       "1.1%",
  "300-level",       "C+",  7,         "8%",
  "300-level",        "F",  3,       "3.4%",
  "400-level",        "A",  8,      "66.7%",
  "400-level",       "A-",  1,       "8.3%",
  "400-level",       "B+",  2,      "16.7%",
  "400-level",       "C-",  1,       "8.3%"
  )
```

```
ggplot(datagra, aes( y=n, x=as.factor(GRDE_CODE))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill=Course.lvl), position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = rel.percent, 
        y = n),
    vjust = -0.2, size = 3,
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    color = "black") +
  labs(title =  "MATH Grade Distribution by Level -Fall 2019 & Fall 2020",
       y="Number of Students",
       x ="",) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Which gives me this [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw4F9.png)

I need the labels to coincide with the actual bars. Hopefully the above can provide enough data to help with a reprex.

Not sure what's wrong though, I've tried using v and h just and position dodge, i've attempted to flip the coordinates and have tried several examples where I call the labels differently. I'm hoping there's a way to maybe even get a line pointing with the relevant percentages/numbers to the corresponding bar itself

Comment: doesn't work for me, I've even tried position_dodge but it doesn't work. I'm wondering if there's a way to get the actual label to have a line pointing directly to the bar itself?

Comment: I just attempted it, width=1 in the position_dodge doesn't work for me

Comment: As @akrun mentions, you should provide some data to give a good reproducible example. You can do so with `dput(head(df))`, then paste the result as code in your question.

Comment: I used the dpasta to convert to a tibble, maybe it'll work in the same fashion? I can always re-edit to use your dput function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `geom_text` doesn't know how to group its data. You need to give it the `fill` or `group` aesthetic in order for it to dodge the text properly. Since you are using the `fill` aesthetic in `geom_bar` you should probably just add `fill` to the `ggplot` call. For example:

```
ggplot(datagra, aes( y=n, x=as.factor(GRDE_CODE), fill=Course.lvl)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = rel.percent, 
        y = n),
    vjust = -0.2, size = 3,
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    color = "black") +
  labs(title =  "MATH Grade Distribution by Level -Fall 2019 & Fall 2020",
       y="Number of Students",
       x ="") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Also, as stated in the comments, it is generally much easier for people to help you if you make a reproducible example.

EDIT: code updated to remove `,`.

Comment: yeah, it's still not working. Also, the data is pretty big and messy and I wouldn't know where to begin creating the data for this purpose.

Comment: You can use the `data()` function to list a set of example data sets. I used as modification of `mtcars` to try working through your problem. `mt <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear, carb) %>% summarize(n = n()) %>% mutate(rel = n / sum(n))`

Comment: I made an edit, hopefully it's decent so I can stop getting dragged

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. There was an extra `,` in the `labs` function. I fixed it in an edit.

Comment: wow, that's insane. your solution worked. Now, do you also know how to separate the bars from each other so it's easier to read?

Comment: You can get space between the bars by adding a `width` parameter and changing the `position` to `position_dodge(`)` in `geom_bar`. i.e `geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(1), width=0.5)`

Comment: Thank you so much. Wish I had more rep to upvote your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out; it's working for me.

I adjusted the class of the percent as things always seem to run a bit smoother for me that way.

```
t <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Course.lvl, ~GRDE_CODE,  ~n, ~rel.percent,
  "100-level",        "A", 95,      "22.1%",
  "100-level",       "A-", 30,         "7%",
  "100-level",        "B", 69,      "16.1%",
  "100-level",       "B-", 24,       "5.6%",
  "100-level",       "B+", 20,       "4.7%",
  "100-level",        "C", 70,      "16.3%",
  "100-level",       "C-", 16,       "3.7%",
  "100-level",       "C+", 25,       "5.8%",
  "100-level",        "D", 33,       "7.7%",
  "100-level",       "D+",  3,       "0.7%",
  "100-level",        "F", 44,      "10.3%",
  "200-level",        "A", 24,      "15.2%",
  "200-level",       "A-", 12,       "7.6%",
  "200-level",        "B", 22,      "13.9%",
  "200-level",       "B-", 10,       "6.3%",
  "200-level",       "B+", 17,      "10.8%",
  "200-level",        "C", 14,       "8.9%",
  "200-level",       "C-", 15,       "9.5%",
  "200-level",       "C+", 13,       "8.2%",
  "200-level",        "D", 13,       "8.2%",
  "200-level",       "D+",  3,       "1.9%",
  "200-level",        "F", 15,       "9.5%",
  "300-level",        "A", 32,      "36.8%",
  "300-level",       "A-", 11,      "12.6%",
  "300-level",        "B",  8,       "9.2%",
  "300-level",       "B-",  9,      "10.3%",
  "300-level",       "B+", 10,      "11.5%",
  "300-level",        "C",  6,       "6.9%",
  "300-level",       "C-",  1,       "1.1%",
  "300-level",       "C+",  7,         "8%",
  "300-level",        "F",  3,       "3.4%",
  "400-level",        "A",  8,      "66.7%",
  "400-level",       "A-",  1,       "8.3%",
  "400-level",       "B+",  2,      "16.7%",
  "400-level",       "C-",  1,       "8.3%"
) %>%
  mutate(rel.percent = gsub('\\%', '',rel.percent),
         rel.percent = as.numeric(rel.percent))
         

t %>% 
ggplot(aes(y=n, x=GRDE_CODE, fill = Course.lvl, group = Course.lvl))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label= paste0(rel.percent, "%")), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust =-.5, size=3) +
  labs(title =  "MATH Grade Distribution by Level -Fall 2019 & Fall 2020",
       y="Number of Students",
       x ="") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("purple","green","steelblue", "grey5"))
```